# Sencha Touch + DeftJS

Tags: touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying out the DeftJS framework in a Sencha Touch application.

But i'm having troubles implementing the newest version (0.6.5)
when it goes over the following lines:

```
classDefinition = Ext.ClassManager.get(this.getClassName());
```

where

```
this.getClassName()    outputs    "TimeSheetApp.store.TotalActualStore"
```

so the following line

```
if (classDefinition.singleton)
```

throws this exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'singleton' of null
```

Any idea what i'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the specified class has either not been loaded or does not exist.

Double-check that the class name you've specified is exactly correct and that it has been loaded via `Ext.require()` in your primary JavaScript file before `Ext.onReady()`, or via the `requires:` annotation on your root Sencha Touch application class.

Even as the author of the Deft JS framework, I ran into this problem this week, too. The error being thrown as of v0.6.5 is not particularly helpful. I filed an issue on GitHub capturing this problem, so you can track progress there:

https://github.com/deftjs/DeftJS/issues/16

We will be adding better error handling and notification in v0.6.6.

In the meantime, correcting the name or adding the missing class requirement should get you going again.

Thanks for checking out Deft JS!

Comment: The Ext.require() was just what i needed.